# Load "event subscribers" dynamically in a PackageServiceProvider

Tags: php, laravel, events, package

I am developing an application in `Laravel 5.4` and my intention is to be able to define different **listeners** (*event subscribers*) at the package level and be able to register them dynamically in my `PackageServiceProvider`.

Currently I am already doing it for some elements such as the **views** (`$this->loadViewsFrom(...)`), **migrations** (`$this->loadMigrationsFrom()`), **langs** (`$this->loadTranslationsFrom()`) ...

**But I can not find a way to register my event subscribers** without having to manually include them in `App\Providers\EventServiceProvider`.

Is there a method `$this->loadEventSubscribersFrom(...)` or something similar that can serve me for what I need? I do not find anything similar in the [official documentation of laravel on **Package Development** section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/packages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in my `PackageServiceProvider@boot` method I can use:

```
\Event::subscribe(new MyEventSubscriberClass());
```

And it works well. But... I don't know if this is a good-practice.